# I have a text view created dynamically no outlet ,I need to change the textview text colour.How could i do this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, textcolor

I have a `text view` created dynamically no outlet ,I need to change the textview text colour.i have set dynamically the selectable "**True**",But the text is always showing in black colour don't know why. I have reached every where in google but not lucky to find the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change font color of UITextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134152/change-font-color-of-uitextview)

Comment: show me your coding which what you have tried untill now.

Comment: @Ranjan is my  answer helps you ?

Answer (score 0):

Please set text color for each `UITextView` which you created dynamically :

```
SomeTextView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Hope This will help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextView *view = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 100, 100)];
view.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextView *txtView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 100, 100)];
txtView.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:txtView];
```

If u want to display the colour  for particular words in textview u can try

```
NSMutableAttributedString *stringText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is awesome"];
```

//Green color for the first four characters.

```
[stringText addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor greenColor] range: NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
```

// Sets the font color of last four characters to yellow.

```
[stringText addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor yellowColor] range: NSMakeRange(14, 10)];
```

You can achieve this by doing it programatically. Use `NSMutableAttributedString`

```
NSMutableAttributedString *stringText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is awesome"];

//Green color for the first four characters.
[stringText addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor greenColor] range: NSMakeRange(0, 4)];

// Sets the font color of last four characters to yellow.
[stringText addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor yellowColor] range: NSMakeRange(14, 10)];
```

Set this text to your `UITextView`. It should work. Also make sure if text changes dynamically you need to care full with `NSMakeRange`.

Comment: Are u still facing Problem...?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way for changing textview text color is

```
UITextView *txtviewTextColor = [[UITextView alloc]init];
txtviewTextColor.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 200, 100);
txtviewTextColor.scrollEnabled = YES;
txtviewTextColor.textColor =[UIColor greenColor];
txtviewTextColor.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:txtviewTextColor];
```