# Change textColor of a UITextView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, uitextview, textcolor

I have an `iOS` project I'm working on using `Xcode7` and `Swift2`. I have a `UITextView` that I'm trying to change the `textColor` of.  It has a black background color.

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134152/change-font-color-of-uitextview) and could not find a `setTextColor`.  I also tried below in the `UIViewController` of where the `UITextView` is located with no luck:

```
@IBOutlet weak var codeText: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.codeText.delegate = self

    codeText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

I then went into the Inspector and tried clicking on the `UITextView` and changing the `textColor` there with no luck of it changing.  Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the `UITextField` in the `Storyboard` and putting a new one.  I connected it to the `ViewController` with an `@IBOutlet` as before. I then went to 'Product' and 'Clean'.  Afterwards I ran my my project and it worked fine.  I still had the newly added `UITextView` called `codeText` assigned to the `UITextFieldDelegate` and works beautifully.  Must have just had a bug in it and needed to start fresh.

Answer (score 13):

on your ViewController remove the line

```
self.codeText.delegate = self
```

You can not assign a value of type "ViewController" to type "UITextViewDelegate?"

```
codeText.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

works just fine.

Comment: codeText is of type `UITextView` and can be assigned to the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You are sure that your codeText variale is not nil? in my opinion your code should work. Please check wether codeText is not nil.

Comment: It is connected to my ViewController with an @IBOutlet.  It's not nil and does show the text I've assigned from within the ViewController, just won't change the color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add NSAttributedString with .foregroundColor: UIColor.label

Comment: It's nice to provide a visual aid; however, your answer should explain how to solve the question with out the need for the visual aid. Also, if you're going to provide code, please do so as text in the body of the answer.